Symfony: Error "DisconnectedClassMetadataFactory" When Using php bin/console make:entity
I am trying to create an Entity in Symfony using the command:
php bin/console make:entity

After providing the entity name, I encounter the following error:
Attempted to load class "DisconnectedClassMetadataFactory" from namespace "Doctrine\ORM\Tools".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

I tyed clear the cache but it had no effect. I trued update composer too. One times tis command start working but in next time problem returns.
Here is my composer.json:
{
    "name": "symfony/skeleton",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "description": "A minimal Symfony project recommended to create bare bones applications",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.13",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.3",
        "doctrine/orm": "^3.1",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.5",
        "phpstan/phpdoc-parser": "^1.33",
        "symfony/asset": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/console": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/doctrine-messenger": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/form": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/intl": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/mime": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/notifier": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
        "symfony/process": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/string": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/translation": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/ux-twig-component": "^2.21",
        "symfony/validator": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^2.2",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.2.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "php-http/discovery": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
            "requirements-checker": "script"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.2.*"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^7.1",
        "symfony/requirements-checker": "^2.0",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "6.2.*"
    }
}

How can I solve my problem? Of course I can create Entities manually, but I prefer create that in cli.

Try to re-install composer. That should fix Your issue:

rm -rf vendor/
composer clear-cache
composer install
php bin/console cache:clear

